# Syntax Error in module.js - Application is blank in IE & Egde

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, meteor, ecmascript-6

I've made an application in Meteor using React. When it runs on Chrome everything works fine and there is no problem. But when i open it in IE or Edge it's just total blank. I think it has something to do with ES2015+ but I can't find the root problem.

As you can see on the image here, it just says "Syntax error in module.js" And afterward a lot of meteor Install is not defined. [Error syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzRMI.png)

Here is my package.json file

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@cleverbeagle/seeder": "^1.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.12",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.0.17",
    "@okgrow/auto-analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "commonmark": "^0.28.1",
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.11",
    "hide-virtual-keyboard": "^1.0.1",
    "ios-sim": "^6.1.2",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "juice": "^4.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "parse-google-place": "^1.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "query-string": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-slider": "^2.1.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-share": "^2.1.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^4.2.0",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.3.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
```

And this is my packages in Meteor:

```js
    meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.5.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.4.1   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.3.4    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.11.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

react-meteor-data
alanning:roles
fourseven:scss
twbs:bootstrap
accounts-base@1.4.2
accounts-password@1.5.1
service-configuration@1.0.11
themeteorchef:bert
fortawesome:fontawesome
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.1
audit-argument-checks@1.0.7
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
dynamic-import@0.4.0
static-html
mdg:seo
universe:i18n
reywood:publish-composite
mdg:meteor-apm-agent
underscore@1.0.10
mdg:geolocation
btafel:accounts-facebook-cordova
```

Anything had same issue? I'm running on Meteor version 1.7.0.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the image I see syntax error, but the error message also tells where in the file modules.js it goes wrong. I would go to that line-number in the file and examine exactly what IE/Edge does not understand. I would guess `import` or `const` keyword is used, but I would know more if I could see the content of the file :)

Comment: Hi @kunukn, Here you have the content of the module.js. See image line **82814** 

https://imgur.com/a/2G1y3R0

I think it's the arrow function and something with it's not compiling it correctly. But i'm not sure how to fix it.. Thanks for you time! :)

Comment: This has been fixed now - we found that the issue was a new version of query-string and downgraded it again made it work.